# I made an onclick rpg mainly using jquery. I'm having a major issue with the random selection of a hero being attacked by the enemy bots

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, conditional-statements

This is my first stack overflow question, however I'll try to be as concise as possible. I made a game in the style of an old school rpg. You have three heroes to choose from, based off the marvel universe, and you choose one of three enemies to attack. After you initiate an attack, a random attack is then initiated by the enemy side. My main issue is that, if one of the hero characters dies and is removed from the game, there is still a chance that the enemy randomly attacks said character. Here are some sources to said game: http://marvel-jquery-rpg.herokuapp.com/ or my github: https://github.com/jdestiny92/jquery_rpg or here is the main js function in question:

```
    // Boss Attack Sequence
function bossAttackSequence(){

heroes = ["cap", "ironman", "deadpool"];

choice = heroes[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];

ultronAttack = Math.floor(Math.random()*(300-200+1)+200);

ultronCrit = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

if(ultronCrit <= 15){
        ultronAttack = Math.floor(ultronAttack + .25*ultronAttack);
    };

if(choice=="cap"){
    $('#attackMessage').show(1000, function(){
    document.getElementById('ultronAttack').play();
    if(ultronCrit <= 15){
        document.getElementById('ultronAttack').pause();
        document.getElementById('ultronCrit').play();
        $('#attackMessage').html('Ultron did a critical hit on Captain America for ' + ultronAttack + ' damage');
    }
    else{
        $('#attackMessage').html('Ultron attacked Captain America for ' + ultronAttack + ' damage');
    };
    reset();
    capHealth = capHealth - ultronAttack;
    $('#capbox').html('Health: ' + capHealth);
    if(capHealth < 0){
        $('#cap').remove();
        $('#capbox').remove();
        $('#capHealth').remove();
        new Audio('letdown.mp3').play();
    };
    if(window.capHealth <=0 && window.ironmanHealth <=0 && window.deadpoolHealth <=0){location.replace('loss.html');};
    });

};

if(choice=="ironman"){
    $('#attackMessage').show(1000, function(){
    document.getElementById('ultronAttack').play();
    if(ultronCrit <= 15){
        document.getElementById('ultronAttack').pause();
        document.getElementById('ultronCrit').play();
        $('#attackMessage').html('Ultron did a critical hit on Ironman for ' + ultronAttack + ' damage');
    }
    else{
        $('#attackMessage').html('Ultron attacked Ironman for ' + ultronAttack + ' damage');
    };
    reset();
    ironmanHealth = ironmanHealth - ultronAttack;
    $('#ironmanbox').html('Health: ' + ironmanHealth);
    if(ironmanHealth < 0){
        $('#ironman').remove();
        $('#ironmanbox').remove();
        $('#ironmanHealth').remove();
        new Audio('impossible2.mp3').play();
    };

});

};

if(choice=="deadpool"){
    $('#attackMessage').show(1000, function(){
    document.getElementById('ultronAttack').play();
    if(ultronCrit <= 15){
        document.getElementById('ultronAttack').pause();
        document.getElementById('ultronCrit').play();
        $('#attackMessage').html('Ultron did a critical hit on Deadpool for ' + ultronAttack + ' damage');
    }
    else{
        $('#attackMessage').html('Ultron attacked Deadpool for ' + ultronAttack + ' damage');
    };
    reset();
    deadpoolHealth = deadpoolHealth - ultronAttack;
    $('#deadpoolbox').html('Health: ' + deadpoolHealth);
    if(deadpoolHealth < 0){
        $('#deadpool').remove();
        $('#deadpoolbox').remove();
        $('#deadpoolHealth').remove();
        new Audio('wrongButton.mp3').play();
        };
    });

};

};
```

And here was my attempt at fixing the enemy attack choice, however it did not work once I inserted it into the previous function:

```
if(capHeatlh<0 && ironmanHeatlh<0){
    heroes = ['deadpool', 'deadpool', 'deadpool'];
};

if(capHeatlh<0 && deadpoolHeatlh<0){
    heroes = ['ironman', 'ironman', 'ironman'];
};

if(deadpoolHeatlh<0 && ironmanHeatlh<0){
    heroes = ['cap', 'cap', 'cap'];
};

if(capHeatlh<0){
    var option1 = ['ironman', 'ironman', 'deadpool'];
    var option2 = ['deadpool', 'ironman', 'deadpool'];

    var coinflip1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

    if(coinflip1==0){
        heroes = option1;
    }
    else{
        heroes = option2;
    };
};

if(ironmanHeatlh<0){
    var option1 = ['cap', 'cap', 'deadpool'];
    var option2 = ['cap', 'deadpool', 'deadpool'];

    var coinflip2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

    if(coinflip2==0){
        heroes = option1;
    }
    else{
        heroes = option2;
    };
};

if(deadpoolHeatlh<0){
    var option1 = ['cap', 'ironman', 'cap'];
    var option2 = ['cap', 'ironman', 'ironman'];

    var coinflip3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

    if(coinflip3==0){
        heroes = option1;
    }
    else{
        heroes = option2;
    };
};
```

Any and all help/feedback will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the heroes array assignemnt out of the scope of the function. Then control your choice by whoever is left in your heroes array:

```
heroes = ["cap", "ironman", "deadpool"]; //move this outside of the function scope, then
```

you choice random index should be determined by the length of the heroes array:

Instead of hardcoding 3 there, you can use .length:

`choice = heroes[Math.floor(Math.random()*heroes.length)];`

When a hero dies, you can drop him out of the array using .splice(index, 1);

so heroes.splice(0, 1) will remove "cap", heroes.splice(1,1) will remove "ironman", heroes.splice(2,1) will remove "deadpool"

That way the next time you run bossSequence, your heroes array may only have 2 heroes left, or 1 hero left, but your random choice will still only be one of the characters that are alive.